# Select Negation of one table from another along with data in master table sql query for oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am stuck with an issue. I have 3 tables in my oracle database.
First table contains all registered employees: ID, FNAME, LNAME
Second table contains all employees(Registered + Unregistered): - ID, FNAME, LNAME
Third table is a master table having all details of employee along with address. ID is common in all 3 tables.

Here my requriment is to write a query which will display all not registered employees with there address details.

Some ID's are null as well in all tables which have to be neglected.

Table 1 - Registered Users
Table 2 - Registered+Not Registered
Table 3 - Master Table which contains additional information

Requirement:- Select ID, Name, Address for not registered users.

Query will be more helpful instead of explanation.

Thanks,

Comment: Hint: LEFT JOIN or NOT EXISTS.

Comment: Hey Raymond, May you look into requirement once and please let me kow the query if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think `not exists` or `not in` does what you want:

```
select m.*
from masters m
where not exists (select 1
                  from registered r
                  where r.id = m.id
                 );
```

Comment: Okay my requirement is select all employees who are not registered. AllEmployeeTable(Registered+Unregisterd) minus RegisterdUser. Which will give me all not registered users. Now for all the unregistered users i have to select address from the 3rd table.